# Can a single venv be used for a multiple flask Web apps?

Tags: python

I am currently following a tutorial to build a web app using the flask framework and so far I've installed several flask extensions in the venv.. but then I want to create another flask app that I would be using for testing, experimenting and learning purposes.. do I have to reinstall flask and it's extensions which are already in the other venv or can I use a single venv?

I tried copying the venv folder from the app I'm working on to the folder of the new app I want to use for testing.. but "from flask import Flask" still shows errors

Comment: Technically, yes, a single venv can be used for multiple projects. It's not a good idea, though. And you wouldn't do it by copying the virtual environment folder—they don't relocate very well. I suggest you go with one environment per project. Disk is cheap.

Comment: So for each project I have to install flask and it's extensions?

Comment: That's the recommended process, yes. It allows each project to have different dependencies, different versions of Flask, etc. Also, you should declare those dependencies in a `pyproject.yaml` / `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` / `requirements.in` and `requirements.txt` / `environment.yml`, or even just a `requirements.txt`, depending on the tooling you use.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's perfectly fine to develop and run multiple flask web apps with a single Python environment, including the `venv`.

But if two projects use a same package and one project should use a version of the package different to a version the other project should use(these cases are rare), you need two Python environments because two different versions of a package can't be installed at one Python environment at the same time.(You can see that by examining sub-directories of a directory in the `sys.path`.)

And don't copy a virtual environment directory created by the `venv`, because it's not documented and not supported.